# git reports merge conflict although files are the same

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-merge, pull-request, git-merge-conflict

I have a master branch and development/Server branch in git.
I created Pull Request and trying to merge development/Server to master branch but I am facing conflict.
I am getting conflicts for 2 files: `.h` and `.cpp`
*"This pull request can't be merged.
You will need to resolve conflicts to be able to merge"*

`git merge` also didn't pass.

When I compare those two files I can see that they are iddentical. Tried it manually and I also checked on online comparison tools (e.g. codebeautify)

Why git reports conflicts although files are identical???

Please give me any hints you might have, I really can't find the solution for this.

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I find it hard to believe that git would complain just because. Let's check the assumption. Can you show us the output of these commands while you are standing on the branch that is setup in the PR? `git diff --name-status @...the-upstream-branch` and `git diff --name-status the-upstream-branch...@` (notice it is `...`, not `..` in both diff commands). Check if the files show up in both outputs.

Comment: Did you check the line endings to be identical too? Or spaces vs. tabs. Or UTF-8 vs UTF-16 encoded files. Or, or, or. `sha1sum` will tell you immediately if two files are identical byte for byte.

Comment: @eftshift0 can you please elaborate if I should wrote "master" instead of the "the-upstream-branch"?

Comment: @knittl how to check on this with `sha1sum`? where, how? thanks in advance

Comment: @Veljko check out v1 of the file, run `sha1sum` on it. check out v2 of the file, run `sha1sum` on it. Compare the hashes.

Comment: @knittl sha1sum are the same!!!
`$ git merge --allow-unrelated-histories  development/ServerGuard
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in base/ServerGuard/ServerGuard.h
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.`
When run sha1sum on dev branch

`sha1sum.exe base/ServerGuard/ServerGuard.h
08bc456e1d1f48e48b4a82605f5a4e4e2432a232 *base/ServerGuard/ServerGuard.h`
Master branch
`sha1sum.exe base/ServerGuard/ServerGuard.h
08bc456e1d1f48e48b4a82605f5a4e4e2432a232 *base/ServerGuard/ServerGuard.h`

Comment: @eftshift0 I have run 2 commands from the development branch: `$ git diff --name-status @...master
fatal: @...master: no merge base` and `$ git diff --name-status master...@
fatal: master...@: no merge base`
What does this mean?

Comment: @Veljko your comment contains one _crucial_ detail that you forgot to mention in your question: `--allow-unrelated-histories`!! (That's why it's so important to include a [mre] with the exact commands that you had run.) Why are you merging unrelated histories? The conflict is "add/add": both (unrelated!) histories have added a file at the same path. I would have expected Git to handle cases when the content is identical, but apparently it does not. I will still verify that independently. But _why_ are you trying to merge unrelated histories?

Comment: I verified in a local repo and there is no conflict when both files have the same content. Are you sure you had the correct file checked out?

Comment: But since both sides of the file are identical and only two files are conflicting: simply resolve the conflict by picking either version and be done with it? Is this the question how to solve the problem or is it a question to understand _why_ there are conflicts (but you know _how_ to resolve them)? Ideally, the post contains code to reproduce the problem

Comment: @knittl I am merging unrelated histories because if I run like this: `$ git merge  development/ServerGuard` this is what I get
`fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`. So basically I am blocked

Comment: @knittl You are right maybe I didn't express myself well - I know how to resolve the conflict but I am frustrated that conflict appears at the first place. Why does this happen when files are completely the same??

Comment: My use case is little bit complex. I am trying to migrate branches with their history from some other SCM platform to Git. Every branch from that other SCM platform reffers to some other project but some of them have some common folders/files. So master branch contains many folders: like base/Folder1, base/Folder2, ... base/ServerGuard.
My branch `development/ServerGuard`  is not created from master branch with `git checkout` but with `git switch` so that it is empty at the start and then I am migrating folders/files/history from some other SCM platform.Now for some files I get merge conflict

Comment: @knittl I would like to know why this problem happens at all because I will be having 60 branches to be merged to master and that's why it would be problematic if I all the time need to resolve conflicts which should not exist at the first place... maybe history records for those 2 files are producing the issue? maybe its not about the files itself but maybe theirs commits are causing the issue? thanks for the support

Comment: @Veljko please add additional, relevant info to the question by [edit]ing it. Comments are not the place to add details. I don't get the error in a sample repo with two unrelated branches and two identical files (not with "ort" strategy nor with "recursive"). Which Git version are you using to perform the merge? I'm running with Git 2.42

Comment: @knittl hey I tried this one: `$ git diff development/ServerGuard master -- base/ServerGuard/ServerGuard.h
diff --git a/base/ServerGuard/ServerGuard.h b/base/ServerGuard/ServerGuard.h
old mode 100644
new mode 100755`
can it be related to something regarding the file permissions?

Comment: @Veljko very likely yes. It is a conflict, Git cannot know if you want the file to be executable or not; you have to explicitly decide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different reasons why a path can be conflicted during merge:

- Both sides of the merge make incompatible textual changes (e.g. change the same line).
- Both sides added a file under the same path with different content.
- One side added a file, the other side added a directory.
- One side changed the file, the other side removed the file.
- The permissions (mode) of the path are incompatible, e.g. one side of the merge adds an executable file, while the second side adds a non-executable file under the same path.

`git status` will tell you which paths are conflicted and which kind of conflict it is.

`git diff` will show you the conflicting changes.

Resolve the conflicts and `git add` the file with the desired content or permissions, then `git commit` the merge.

Comment: thanks, can you please assist me with this issue as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77351555/git-merging-from-2nd-branch-after-folder-is-deleted-from-the-1st-branch thanks a lot...